# Error while accessing categories in magento back end

Tags: magento-1.9, category, attributes, catalog, category-attribute

Wondering if anyone can help. I had a theme installed called **mango**. Due to the author not supporting it anymore and it being absolutely terrible for support etc, I had no choice but to get a refund on it.

The author is refusing to provide any removal instructions at all.

The error I'm experiencing is as below. I've now installed a new theme, and attempted to manually remove all the previous theme files.

Please can anyone assist.

```
Source model "mango/category_attribute_source_tab_mode" not found for attribute "sw_product_staticblock_tab_1"

Trace:
#0 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(44422): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "m...')
#1 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#2 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes.php(113): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset))
#3 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#4 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(2612): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#5 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs.php(140): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(1987): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#7 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(28609): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#8 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form.php(55): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'tabs')
#9 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(1987): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form->_prepareLayout()
#10 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(28609): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#11 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container.php(93): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...')
#12 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(1987): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container->_prepareLayout()
#13 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(28609): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#14 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(28625): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#15 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(28392): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#16 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(28358): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#17 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(28363): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#18 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(14198): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#19 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(14123): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#20 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#21 /home/harrison/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(201): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#22 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(14272): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController->editAction()
#23 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(18750): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#24 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(18280): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#25 /home/harrison/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(21176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#26 /home/harrison/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#27 /home/harrison/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#28 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you installed in the past an extension and uninstalled it, but there were some attributes that remained in the database.

Backup your db and run this query on it.

```
DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE source_model = 'mango/category_attribute_source_tab_mode';
```

Comment: Marius ! You the Man ! Thank you very much! That fixed my problem ! 
:-)

Comment: Welcome to SE. If an answer solves your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you have theme package, then you can manually match and remove respective folders and files from your installation.

If not, then you need to follow below process:

- Find module bootstrap files in **`app/etc/modules`** folder. Check **codePool** of modules and delete xml files from this folder.
- Go to codePool by navigating to **`app/code/<codePool>`** folder and open module(s) **`config.xml`** file(s) which are located under **`app/code/<codePool>/<package-name>/<module-name>/etc`** folder.
- Note location and name of layout files, translation files and email template files (if any), and then delete **`app/code/<codePool>/<package-name>/<module-name>`** folder.
- Delete email template files and translation files.
- Find layout file(s) under app/design//layout folder and note down names and locations of js, css and template files.
- Delete respective js, css and template files (if any).
- Delete layout file(s).
- Delete module's entries from **`core_config_data`** table.
- Delete module tables and attributes.

**Note:** If required, flush cache and do reindexing.

After this process, I hope you will not see such errors.